# How to put simple quote in a concat - Xpath 1.0

Tags: xml, xpath

So I want to create this string :

```
insert into TABLE values(651665, 'c e d b f a i');
```

I already managed to create this string with Xpath :

```
concat('insert into TABLE values(', //OneNode/@id, ', `', //myNode, '`);')
```

Which gives me :

```
insert into TABLE values(651665, ` c e d b f a i `);
```

But now I want to replace the ` by ' . Is there a way to do that in Xpath 1.0 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrapped for legibility:

```js
concat(
  'insert into TABLE values(', 
  "'", 
  //OneNode/@id, 
  ', ',
  //myNode, 
  "'",
  ');'
)
```

XPath strings can begin with either `"` or `'` and they cannot contain their delimiter, i.e. there is no string escaping mechanism.

This means the above is valid XPath, but additional escaping is necessary to make this valid inside XML attributes (like XSLT `<xsl:value-of select="..." />`):

```
<xsl:value-of select="
concat(
  'insert into TABLE values(', 
  &quot;'&quot;, 
  //OneNode/@id, 
  ', ',
  //myNode, 
  &quot;'&quot;,
  ');'
)
" />
```